# How to Open/Read Uploaded CSV Files in Views

Tags: django, csv, django-views

I have a model named source where files are uploaded to, that looks like this:

```
class Source(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and I can call it easily in views like so:

```
def source_details(request, source_id):
    context_dict = {}

    data_source = Source.objects.get(id=source_id)
    context_dict['data_source'] = data_source
```

Additionally here are my urls:

```
url(r'^source/(?P<source_id>[\w\-]+)/$', views.source_details),
```

I want to open the csv file that the view is getting so I can loop through each line and display it in a table, any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: show your urls, did you have list view?

Comment: No list view, I've updated my post to show the urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it?

```
f = data_source.file
f.open(mode='rb') 
source = f.readlines()
f.close()
context_dict['data_source'] = source
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what i'm trying to accomplish. Your solution would work great, but only to list all the uploaded files. However, I want to show the contents of the file.